# stylometry using machine learning in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

We are trying to implement a system that takes input as novels and can extract the author's styles(word length,sentence length,usage of comma etc) so that it can predict the authorship of document; when we give an anonymous document of any trained author.

our trained system have to learn author's style by using machine learning algorithm.
is there any problem of using Naive Bayes algorithm to train our system to extract each author's style. Otherwise, can you please give me a better alternative??

We are trying to get implement it in python.
Can you tell me where to start? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by looking at [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html): a machine learning library with a lot of implemented algorithms.

For text classification, Naive Bayes does not usually achieve the best results. Look at Support Vector Machines and algorithms based on ideas from them, such as (you can search for these on the scikit website and go from there): SGDClassifier, PassiveAggressiveClassifier and LinearSVC.

Scikit also implements Naive Bayes classifiers, so have a look at those as well.

I wouldn't start by manually deciding what is relevant to an author's style. Look into CountVectorizer (bag of words model) and TfidfVectorizer (tf-idf weighting for the bag of words model), which should build decent features for you to start with.

Answer (score 0):

There are many python libraries that could be used to measure different linguistic aspects of your input text and then using this values as features would probably enhance the quality of your model. I'll name a few here that can help you measuring aspects like Subjectivity, Complexity, Informality, Specificity etc:

[TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/)

[Domain-Agnostic-Sentence-Specificity-Prediction](https://github.com/wjko2/Domain-Agnostic-Sentence-Specificity-Prediction)

[Readability](https://pypi.org/project/readability/)

[TextStat](https://pypi.org/project/textstat/)

[Python Semantic Complexity Analyser](https://github.com/afel-project/pySemanticComplexity)

[Uncertainty](https://github.com/meyersbs/uncertainty)

[Lexical Diversity](https://pypi.org/project/lexical-diversity/)

[Lexical Richness](https://pypi.org/project/lexicalrichness/)

I hope that helps!